# Prove that $\left|\dfrac{\sin ax - \sin bx}{x }\right| \le |a-b|$

Tags: calculus

> Use the mean value theorem to prove that $\left|\dfrac{\sin ax - \sin bx}{x }\right| \le |a-b|$ for $x\ne 0$ and $a,b \in \Bbb R$.

Answer (score 3):

One has
$$\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}=f'(c), \qquad c \in (a,b),$$
then applying it to $f(x)=\sin x$, $f'(x)=\cos x$, one may conclude with $|\cos x|\le 1$.